# Presto SQL - Converting a date string to date format?

Tags: sql, presto

I'm on presto and have a date formatted as varchar that looks like

```
"2022-03-01T09:24:58+09:00"
```

and I tried

```
 date_parse(filename,  '%Y-%m-%d %T+09:00')
 date_parse(ts,  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')`
```

and give me an error

```
Invalid format: "2022-03-01T09:24:58+09:00" is malformed at "T09:24:58+09:00"
```

How do I convert this?

Answer (score 0):

```
--- Given dates like 2022-03-01T09:24:58+09:00

SELECT with_timezone(
           date_parse(substr(dates, 1, 19),
                      '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s')
           substr(dates, 20)
       )
...

-- Output:
                         _col0
2022-03-01 09:24:58.000 +09:00
```

Comment: You should also just try: `from_iso8601_timestamp(date_col)` I think this might match the formatting, but can't test it until tomorrow.

Comment: @BeRT2me `from_iso8601_timestamp` should work.